# Ideal why to track active websocket connections?

Tags: django, websocket, monitoring, channel

I'm using Django 2+ and Channels 2+ with redis.  I'm trying to reduce my ws connections on the client side and I wanted to be able track active connections but I'm finding it difficult to find an answer.

Eventually this is something I want to track using netdata or something like it. Is there an integrated way or simple method to see how many websocket connections are open on a server?

I will have http traffic going to the same port so I would like to be able to tell the difference between http and ws.

Ideas?

Comment: Looking for the same answer